# How can I set the axes in the VariableFeaturePlot?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, seurat

I perform scRNAseq analysis and I will plot the highly variable feature. The problem is that I can see the plot on Jupyter notebook but the graph is compressed. I mean, I have to set the axes because you can't read the numbers. How do I know the range to set? how can I use this range to set the axes? is there a default setting for the axes?

This is my script:

```
Sun <-FindVariableFeatures(Sun, selection.method = "vst", nfeatures = 2000)
top10 <- head(VariableFeatures(Sun), 10)
head(top10)
plot1 <- VariableFeaturesPlot(Sun)
plot2 <- LabelPoints(plot = plot1, points = top10)
plot1 + plot2
```